# How to create a step-by-step progress bar?

Tags: android, animation, progress-bar, android-animation, android-progressbar

I need to create a step-by-step `progressBar`, which should look like this:
[image]

except the colors should be solid. The idea of the whole thing is, that the progress should move (with animation) as the user moves to the next screen. I found only two libraries (the second one is based on the first one), which offer the desired views, but they are `LinearLayout`s and I don't think I can animate them that easily. [Library 1](https://github.com/anton46/Android-StepsView) and [Library 2](https://github.com/baoyachi/StepView). So I thought it might happen with a linear `progressBar`, where I use a different animation for each step (I have only three steps, so it wouldn't be much of a problem). For example to move it from point 0 to 20 for step one, from 20 to 50 for step two, and from 50 to 100 for step 3. Is this the right way to achieve the desired outcome, or is there a better solution? I am not that experienced with progress bars and animations, so any guidance and recommendations are highly welcomed!